# Collation help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have issue with collation on a stored procedure, I think the issue is in this section but I don't know enough about collation to resolve it, ive tried adding it into various sections but it hasn't worked. If it shouldn't go in this section then I can look at the rest of the query as I it should be added anywhere that I have used the temp table?

The collation issue I have is:

conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS"

```
    create table #tmp_NoRotadayOff (DayOfYear datetime, Rota varchar(10), RotaTemplate varchar(50))
```

Note: I modified my original answer to remove some of my code, only the bit left was actually affected and caused the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default collation for tempdb is the instance collation.  You can specify DATABASE_DEFAULT at the column level for temp tables in order to use the current database default collation instead.  Try:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_NoRotadayOff
    (
      DayOfYear datetime
    , Rota varchar(10) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    , RotaTemplate varchar(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    );
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks for your help, I had forgot about the database_default syntax but that has worked brilliant